# Calibrating Hull White volatility on swap rate volatility

Tags: volatility, calibration, hullwhite

I'm strugling with the Hull-White 1F model. I'am trying to calibrate the volatility with the swap rate volatility. Here is the model I'am curently working on :
$$
\begin{align}
dr_t = a(b-r_t)dt + \sigma_t^{HW} dW_t
\end{align}
$$
Some one gave me a code that compute de HW1F volatility, with the swap rate volatility for a maturity $T_i$ and tenor $\delta_i$, by inversing the formulae bellow. From my understanding $\sigma_t^{Mkt}$ is the swap rate volatility at time $t$
$$
\begin{align}
\sigma^{Mkt}_{T_i} &= VF(T_i,\delta_i) \sqrt{\frac{1}{T_i}\int_0^{T_i}(\sigma^{HW}_s)^2e^{2as} ds} \\
\\
VF(T_i,\delta_i) &= \frac{S(T_i,\delta_i)}{a}\times \bigg[\frac{P(0,T_i)e^{-aT_i}-P(0,T_i+\delta_i)e^{-a(T_i+\delta_i)}}{P(0,T_i)-P(0,T_i+\delta_i)} -  \sum_{j=1}^{\delta_i} \frac{P(0,T_i+j)e^{-a(T_i+j)}}{\sum_{k=1}^{\delta_i}P(0,T_i+k)}  \bigg] \\
\\
S(T_i,\delta_i) &=\frac{P(0,T_i)-P(0,T_i+\delta_i)}{\sum_{k=1}^{\delta_i}P(0,T_i+k)}
\end{align}
$$

I have understand the principle but don't know where this formulae for $\sigma^{Mkt}_t$ came from. I have compute the volatility of the swap rate by using Itô formulae on $S(T_0,T_n)$ but came up with this formulae (might be some small mistake):
$$
\sigma_t^S = \sigma_t^{HW}\bigg[\frac{S(T_0,T_n)}{a}\bigg(e^{-a(T_n-t)}+\frac{e^{-a(T_0-t)}-e^{-a(T_n-t)}}{a}+\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nP(t,T_i)e^{-a(T_i-t)}}{\sum_{i=1}^nP(t,T_i)}\bigg)+\frac{P(t,T_n)}{\sum_{i=1}^nP(t,T_i)}\frac{e^{-a(T_0-t)}-e^{-a(T_n-t)}}{a}\bigg]
$$

I have also compute the volatility for an approximation of the swap rate $\tilde{S}(T_0,T_n) = \frac{P(0,T_n)}{\sum_{i=1}^nP(0,T_i)}\bigg[\frac{P(t,T_0)}{P(t,T_n)}-1\bigg] $ (see [calibration-hull-white](https://people.kth.se/%7Eaaurell/Teaching/SF2975_HT17/calibration-hull-white.pdf) page 6) and came up with this formulae

$$
\sigma_t^{\tilde{S}} = \sigma^{HW}_t \frac{\tilde{S}(T_0,T_n)}{a} \bigg( \frac{P(0,T_n)e^{-a(T_0-t)}-P(0,T_n)e^{-a(T_n-t)}}{P(t,T_n)-P(t,T_n)} \bigg)
$$

If any one know where the formulae for $\sigma^{Mkt}_t$ came from I would be pleased to know.

Every result is expressed using the risk free measure.